# Jasmine Testing knockout.js with requirejs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, knockout.js, requirejs, jasmine

I am having trouble getting my Jasmine test file to get data from my knockoutjs files. I am able to create knockout observables and test those in the the spec file but not other files. For some reason when I try to access `mainViewModel()` in the spec file from the viewmodel.js file it is not found. I have all the requirejs files included/defined but for some reason it is still not working.

Here is my code:

viewmodel.js:

```
define(["knockout", "jquery"], function (ko, $) {

   var data = {
       Name:"The Plan", 
       Id: 1
   };

   var TestViewModel = function (data) {
       var self = this;

       self.planName = ko.observable(data.Name);
       self.planId = ko.observable(data.Id);

       return self;
   }

   function mainViewModel() {
       var self = this;

       self.plan = ko.observableArray([]);
       self.plan.push(new TestViewModel(data));
   }

   return mainViewModel;

});
```

someSpec.js file:

```
define(["knockout", "jquery"], function (ko, $) {

describe("MyTestSpec", function () {

    var viewmodel, data;

    beforeEach(function () {
        require(["knockout", "jquery", "testsViewModel"], function(ko, $, tvm){
             viewmodel = tvm.mainViewModel();
        });
    });

    it("should be able to connect to View Model file", function () {        
        expect(viewmodel.Id).toBe(1);
    });
});
});
```

index.html file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/boot.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
      paths: {
        "jquery": './Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        "knockout": './Scripts/knockout.debug', 
        "testViewModel" :"./Scripts/viewmodel",
      }
    });
    // list spec files here
    require(["knockout","jquery","specs/someSpec", "testViewModel"], function () {
        window.onload();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of things that you need to fix:

1. The [AMD `require` function with a callback](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/require.md) is asynchronous. This means that `viewmodel` won't be set until after your tests have run. Instead of using `require`, just include `testViewModel` as a dependency in your test's `define` call. Alternatively, you can use the synchronous API form: `tvm = require('testViewModel')`.
2. `viewmodel.js` is returning the `mainViewModel` **function** as the module export. So that's what you'll get when referencing it elsewhere. So instead of `viewmodel = tvm.mainViewModel()`, you'd use `viewmodel = tvm()`.

Comment: Great suggestions, it worked with some additional fixes. `mainViewModel()` was not returning anything, so the variables/functions declared were private and accessible by the someSpec.js. I just added `return TestViewModel(data)` along with your suggestions and it worked fine.

Comment: @FahadJameel I am doing testing with knockout and requirejs too. I find it puzzling to mock out dependency used by requirejs. How did you solve this?